# float of powers of numbers in python

Tags: python

how i calculate power of number in python i just have a red message in mu compiler

i tried to search but i have nothing

```
import math


number = float(input("Type in a number: "))

print (math.log(14 * number,10))**2.5
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/murtadho/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/adsasdas.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       print (math.log(14 * number,10))**2.5 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'float'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your statement `print (math.log(14 * number,10))**2.5`you misplaced the parenthesis, so you can make that into individual statements

```
re=math.log(14 * number,10)**2.5
print(re)
```

or enclose everything in parenthesis

```
print(math.log(14 * number,10)**2.5)
```

Comment: calculate logaruthm first after that calculate the power of numbers?

Comment: i saw from anither site that is a logarithm sytnax and i need to logarithm base 10